# How to create a route in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I've built an ionic 3 app with sidemenu.
Right now, the navigation was implemented by push/pop.

When I go to landing page (www.XXX.com), it's loading the newest 20 events and add them to the list on landing page.

But I need to go to (www.XXX.com/:id) and add that specific event to the list only.

I'm stuck with this and wondering how to implement on ionic 3.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the URL of the page and get the param in the url, using the following code

```
// Get your param by manipulating URL string
let sId = location.href.split("#")[1].split("/")[1];
```

OR

If you need much cleaner approach, use segment in IonicPage.

```
Declate IonicPage as 

    @IonicPage({
        segment: 'page/:id'
    })
```

and retrieve param as

```
constructor(navParams: NavParams){
    let sId = this.navParams.get('id');
}
```